# How to remove a second hash added by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I am using a lot of hashes in my URL for displaying messages and stuff, but I have a problem. It is fine when you click on a conversation to read it:

[image]

But, look what happens when the user attaches another hash to the end: (the subject disappears because the JavaScript gets confused)

[image]

(Click images to view larger versions)

How can I remove that second hash *if* there is one? I did this in Gmail before and it automatically removed them. So, how can I do this with my system? Here's my hash code:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var messageID = window.location.hash.replace('#!/message/', '');
    var msgSubject = $('#subject_' + messageID).text();
    //the below code checks if conversation exists
    $.get('tools.php?type=id_check&id=' + messageID, function(data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                readMessage(messageID, msgSubject);
            }, 200);
        }
        else {
            alertBox('The requested conversation does not exist.', 2500);
            window.location = '#';
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
var matches = window.location.hash.match(/#!\/message\/(\d+)/);
if (matches) {
    var messageId = matches[1];
    // ...
}
```

This will capture a series of only digits after `#!/message/`. If the hash contains `#!/message/123`, then `matches` will be an array

```
['#!/message/123', '123']
```

and so `matches[1]` will contain the message id. If there is anything before or after it in the hash, it will be ignored. If there are no matches, `matches` will be `null`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Will `matches[1]` return the ID that is in the hash? And, will it remove the extra hash or will it just keep it? Sorry if you thought I meant that I rather it do nothing. I'll edit my question so it will make more sense if it doesn't already.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks! I don't know anything about regexp... they're hard for me to understand. I tried doing this: `if(hash.match('message') {` but that didn't work, probably because you need symbols in it too, not just words, correct?

Comment: @Nathan `.match()` will work with just a string as well, but in most of those cases, using `.indexOf()` is better. The parentheses in the regex above captures a series `+` of digits `\d` so you're able to use the id.

Comment: Wait, I think that the `.match(/#!message\/(\d+)/);` isn't quite right because my hashes are `#!/message/55837` but the regexp doesn't have that slash in there right before the word 'message'. How do I add that in? It isn't gonna work without it, it looks like...

Comment: @Nathan Np! Yes, you can just add that in, but the forward slash is a special character in regex, so it must be escaped with a backslash. Will update...